# How to improve performance when searching by id in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.1.

The cluster consists of 5 nodes and uses 16gb memory.

I store some data in the ES using the document's ID, and retrieve the data through the get request using the ES JAVA Client.

I have tried several tests.

Sometimes the response time is slightly slower.

Perhaps it seems to be late when the first request occurs after not making a get request on that index for some time.

Is there a way to improve performance when retrieving data through the document's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason for poor performance.

I have found that search performance drops when a lot of documents are inserted in bulk in an Elasticsearch cluster.

Resolved after adjusting bulk size.